# Winforms Panel Size

Tags: c#, winforms

In my form I have a panel with autosize = true.

The panel contains a SplitContainer control with 2 panels arranged horizontally.

The top panel contains a datagridview and the bottom panel contains a textbox.

Is there a way I can programmatically resize the top panel, and hence the entire SplitContainer based on changes in the height of the datagridview (determined by the number of rows)

UPDATE:
I am now able to resize the SplitContainer which has Dock = Bottom, however, the Layout event of the parent panel does not get fired in response to changes in the height of the SplitContainer control even thought the parent panel has Autosize = True

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include how new rows are added!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the splitter distance of the SplitContainer based on the height of the grid.

> **SplitterDistance** Gets or sets the location of the splitter, in pixels, from the left or top edge of the SplitContainer.

Via https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.splitterdistance(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit**
What worked for me was to set Dock for the SplitContainer to **None**, which then allowed me to set the size of the SplitContainer (calling SplitContainer.Height) and having the panel resize itself to fit the SplitContainer.

**Edit 2** 
To allow the SplitContainer to auto-size its width, you can try the following:

```
splitContainer.Width = this.ClientRectangle.Width - (splitContainer.Location.X * 2)
```

This.ClientRectangle.Width should get the width of the window without the border (if the parent is the form).

Comment: I already tried changing the SplitterDistance but it doesn't achieve my desired goal because I want the entire SplitContainer height to be resized not just a panel within it.

Comment: I already tried changing the SplitterDistance but it doesn't achieve my desired goal because I want the entire SplitContainer height to be resized not just a panel within it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize  you updated your response.  I tried this, however, it present another problem because I want the SplitContainer to autosize it's width when I resize the width of the form.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I felt it was a bad recommendation. I edited my answer above again. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Turns out I am able to change the height of the SplitContainer even when Dock = Bottom because it when I set the height of the SplitContainer it fired the SizedChanged event for the SplitContainer and the Height value was updated, however, it doesn't fire the Layout event for the parent Panel control even thought I set the Autosize property for this panel to true.

Comment: @H.Tran Would it be possible to update your question with the current code? If the SplitContainer is a child of the panel, the panel's Layout event should fire when you make changes to the SplitContainer.

Comment: @H.Tran Does the panel itself resize when the SplitViewContainer does? What is the dock setting set to for the panel itself?

Comment: Dock for parent panel is Bottom and the SizedChanged did not  fire in response to changing the height of the child SplitContainer control..I added event handlers for the SizeChanged event for both control and only the one for the SplitContainer was reached.

Comment: @H.Tran So both the SplitContainer and the Panel have Dock = **Bottom**? I added this scenario to my test project and my panel does resize when I modify the size of my SplitContainer. Is your panel set to GrowAndShrink? Or just Grow? I confirmed that if I have AutoSizeMode = to GrowOnly, and my SplitContainer is not docked, it will not call the SizeChanged event for Panel1.

Comment: I figure out the source of the problem.  At some point in the code, the Visibility of the Panel was set to false.  Man, I knew it was something retarded.  Thing is I'm modifying existing code so I don't know everything that went into it..Thanks so much for you help!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that I dont manage to understand, if I force the panel size in the code the object gets the right size.
If I define the panel size 300x300 in the IDE, later is shown smaller and the lines are not visible.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
    }
```